# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' in wordEquiv[i]

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

```
var number : UInt16 = 20_168
var numberString : String = String(number)
var wordEquiv  = [ "1": "One", "2": "Two", "3": "Three" , "4": "Four" ,  "5": "Five", "6": "Six", "7": "Seven", "8": "Eight", "9": "Nine"]
for i in numberString.characters {
    print("\(i) - \(wordEquiv[i]!)")
}
```

When i try to print wordEquiv[key], it seems to be working. But when i try to use it in a loop, it shows an error, how to fix this? Because i'm trying to display each character equivalent of numberString to words.

Comment: If you need to iterate over a collection by using indices, then you actually don't want a dictionary where keys are indices: you want an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i fixed it, i found out that incompatible types of keys are the error, i try to put a type of character as key in the for loop instead of string.
Here is the correct answer

```
var number : UInt16 = 20_168
var numberString : String = String(number)
var wordEquiv : [Character : String]  = ["0": "Zero", "1": "One", "2": "Two", "3": "Three" , "4": "Four" ,  "5": "Five", "6": "Six", "7": "Seven", "8": "Eight", "9": "Nine"]
for i in numberString.characters {

    print("\(i) - \(wordEquiv[i]!)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because character and `String` are different types. Since your `wordEquiv` dictionary takes a `String`, add an appropriate conversion:

```
print("\(i) - \(wordEquiv[String(i)]!)")
```

Alternatively, you could make your dictionary "map" from character to `String`, and avoid the conversion.

**Note:** Your code is going to break on printing `0`, because the dictionary does not contain a description for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code -

```
let number : UInt16 = 20_168
var numberString : String = String(number)
var wordEquiv  = [ "1": "One", "2": "Two", "3": "Three" , "4": "Four" ,  "5": "Five", "6": "Six", "7": "Seven", "8": "Eight", "9": "Nine"]
for i in numberString.characters {
    let string = String(i)
    if let word = wordEquiv[string] {
        print("\(i) - \(wordEquiv[string]!)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Removed a crash, plz check now.